# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'evp_bytestokey' in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have installed the soap(`npm install soap`) but when using soap (`var soap = require('soap')`)
its giving the error. Please help me I am stuck on this point.

Comment: Hi Sharib, welcome to StackOverflow, can you post the errors? Also, please take the time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for help :).. ERROR in ./node_modules/browserify-cipher/browser.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'evp_bytestokey'..

Comment: Do you have more code you are able to share? From the error, it looks like you're missing the `browserify-cipher` package.

Comment: sure. package.json file. var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
 entry: {
   app: './js/app.js',
   app1:'./js/app1.js',
 },
 output: {
  path: __dirname,
  filename: '[name].bundle.js'
 },
 watch: true,
 module: {
  loaders: [
   {
    test: /.jsx?$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    query: {
     presets: ['es2015', 'react']
    }
   }

  ]
 } ,
   node: {
  //   console: 'empty',
     fs: 'empty',
     net: 'empty',
     tls: 'empty'
   }
};

Comment: "name": "reactjsconnectwithapi", "version": "1.0.0",  "main": "index.js",  "scripts": { "babel": "babel", "webpack": "webpack", "test": "echo\"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1" }, "author": "sharib",  "license": "ISC","dependencies": { "babel-core": "^6.25.0", "babel-loader":^7.1.1","babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1","babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1", "es6-promise": "^4.1.1", "mobservable-react-devtools":3.0.1","mobx": "^3.2.0", "mobx-react": "^4.2.2", "react": "^15.6.1","react-dom": "^15.6.1","soap":"^0.19.2","superagent":^3.5.2",webpack":^3.0.0" },"devDependencies": {},"description": ""

Comment: Hi Sharib, can you edit the post and put your code in there? It's hard to read in the comments with the character limits and the lack of formatting.